# Get data like in database order without sorting it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has ShipCountry, ShipCity and Freight column in SQL database. I tried to retrieve data from that table by using the below query.

```
Select ShipCountry from CountryDetails Group by ShipCountry
```

If i run this query i am getting results in Ascending order. Instead of this i need data in database order. How to achieve this through SQL query?

**Note:** If i run the below query, it will return the data in Database order. I am getting sorted data when i added group by clause in my query.

```
Select ShipCountry from CountryDetails
```

Comment: Hello. You question is a bit unclear. Could you please present a fictional set of data and what you want to be the result of your query? Thanks

Comment: Just a note, there is no real concept of "database order". That's merely the order that the database happened to load the rows from memory/disk. This can change over time, between database restarts, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here what i mention database order is data stored or entered order in table. From your point database order can change over time, between database restarts.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used? Are you trying to do SELECT DISTINCT?

Answer (score 6):

The use of group by for ordering is improper  ..  (group by is for aggregation function as min, max or count)

if you need  a specific order use `order by` instead

```
Select ShipCountry from CountryDetails Order  by ShipCountry
```

otherwise if want not order use simply

```
Select ShipCountry from CountryDetails
```

Remember that the values store in db have not a proper order  ..and are selected in the sequence used for retrive the data.

Each time you need an order you must esplicitally use order by

for avoid "redundant values"  .. use distinct and not group by  eg:

```
Select distinct ShipCountry from CountryDetails
```

Comment: Thanks. I want not order. I used simply the below query.

Select ShipCountry from CountryDetails

If i run this it will return the redundant ShipCountry values. To avoid redundant values i have added group by clause in my query. 

My aim is, i don't want order like asc or desc and i don't want redundant data.

Comment: @UmapathyS As long as you realize that the database order can change at any given time due to changes in the distribution of the data. This means that the sort order of your resultset might change from one day to another. If that is something you can live with, by all means just use a `SELECT FROM`.

Comment: i have update the answer  adding distinct for remove  duplicated  values ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Just want him to be fully aware of what he's asking ;) I've seen it happen when we got complaints that the sort order in a grid changed. As it turned out, that morning the statistics on the table caused the query optimizer to return the data in a different order than before.

Comment: @SchmitzIT  You have exactly described the situation .. it's a good comment .. if you put it as a answer/sggestions deserves an  upvote ..  let me know

Comment: @scaisEdge - Done. I threw in some additional explanation as well. I think for this particular case, your answer is great, but perhaps some future visitor could benefit from a bit more background info.

Answer (score 2):

As already has been stated, what you describe might lead to unexpected results fro your end users.

Let's assume you have a table without any indexes or keys (A so-called heap). A heap pretty much can be compared to a phone book (yeah, I've been around for a while) consisting of hundreds of pages, on which information is randomly ordered. A heap is exactly that; A lot of randomly ordered data. Whenever you query from such a table, the query analyzer will do its very best to figure out what the fastest way to deliver the data is.

Such decisions from the query analyzer are guided by statistics; a collection of metrics about the data and the distribution thereof. SQL Server uses these statistics to figure out the cardinality (the uniqueness of values), and thus pick the fastest way to return data.

When you simply issue a `SELECT * FROM myTable` on a heap, those statistics will determine the order in which your data is returned. However, this also means that over time, the statistics will change, as more data flows into the table. This has the effect that the sort order of your data today is not necessarily the sort order in which the data is returned tomorrow, or even five minutes from now.

If that is fine with your end users, then a `SELECT * FROM myTable` is the right solution for you. But, if you absolutely need to have the data returned in a certain order, you should always implement an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the same database order in most cases if you have sorted by primary key it will be the same without ordering as you say:

here the id is the primary key, and if you can not use the primary key add an identity column and use it:

id     name

1      elly

2      ahmad

3      joseph

4      omar

Comment: If only every table would have a PK. Too many times in the wild, a table is just a heap, thanks to non-database savvy developers :(

Comment: Welcome ("i understand what you said :("), every table have only one PK and Identity is not a PK, PK may be an Identity, PK may be text and in case of text the order wanted will not be available, so, by adding a new number identity column the order wanted can be afforded